# How to check whether the PCIe Memory-mapped BAR region is cacheable or uncacheable

Tags: caching, x86, cpu-cache, pci-e, memory-mapping

I want to know the way to check the PCIe Memory-mapped BAR region is **cacheable or not**.

Is there any way to check the setting value or not? Or is it just configured uncacheable in hardware-way??
(I saw some post and articles that *"MMIO memory region is always uncacheable"* but I want to check or confirm the fact)

I configured PCIe device using the Xilinx FPGA and Xilinx PCIe IP. Also host cpu is Intel x86 Xeon CPU.

Comment: It is controlled by the MTRR MSRs, page tables, the PAT MSR, and by EPT when in a guest. So you may have to check several places for a complete picture. See the Intel SDM, volume 3, chapter 12.